# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("rd-content>

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Please help! I am trying to make a validators to my inputs , but no matter what it never works. 
usings Anguar 8 + ionic 4
**The error**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("rd-content>
```

[the Problem message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXOG2.png)

**The app module**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import {NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule, NgbModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule

],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhtHH.png)

Comment: Can you show the form itself and how you build it?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I added it

Comment: Please don't add images of code to your question - you should add the code itself. Also, that's just the HTML. The code you use to build the `login` form group is also relevant